# Is this SQL syntax correct?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this line:

```
RECENT_EVENTS_CONDITION = '(actor_type = \'User\' AND actor_id IN (SELECT followed_id 
                                                                     FROM relationships 
                                                                    WHERE follower_id = user_id))'
```

My main question is whether `user_id` is correct. What I want to do is to find the records where `actor_id` coincides with the ids of the followed users by the current user. The `WHERE follower_id = user_id` concerns me because `user_id` shouldn't be an entire column but rather the specific id of the current user. How should I fix this? Or is it already correct?

Comment: 1. What do you mean?? 2. user_id seems entirely valid 3. consider running your SQL queries instead of butcher butchering them and asking if they work.

Comment: i mean will user_id refer to the id of the current user?

Comment: Without having a table spec or at the very least the entire query, how do you expect an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want:

```
"..query.. SELECT followed_id   FROM relationships  WHERE follower_id = #{user_id}"
```

Comment: ahh, my friend interpolation :)

Comment: absolutely :) Good luck @Justin

Answer (score 2):

`user_id` needs to be a parameter.  Without knowing which language you are using (e.g., is this a PHP app?) or the context overall, I can't give you the exact syntax you need.

Comment: ahh sorry... Ruby on Rails... would it need to be `:user_id`?

Comment: @Justin Meltzer I don't know RoR, so I still can't give you the syntax, but that's a pretty good guess...  You'll need to set the parameter's value before using it, of course.